# Swift - Tableview Cells Stay Highlighted - Except for Top One - No Matter What

Tags: swift, tableview

So I'm new to swift and I've been having some problems getting all of my tableview cells to deselect after performing the segue. Right now all of the cells stay highlighted after I perform the segue, except the top one. The top one is selectable too and performs the segue, but it has no highlighting at all.

This is strange behavior but I have tried all of the basics.

I've tried

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

I've tried

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let selectionIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionIndexPath, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

I've also tried it in the prepare for segue method.

I've also tried it from the cell: cell.selectionStyle = .none

I've also tried changing "selection" in the story board to none.

Nothing seems to change the behavior so I'm at a loss. I think I've messed up something somewhere and can't find what it is.

Here is my tableview class in its entirety if anyone wants to take a look.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase



class DraftListCell : UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var playerName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playerPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priceRemaining: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var vsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var injuredLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var gameTimeLabel: UILabel!

}


class NBADraftList: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource, FIRDatabaseReferenceable{

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var players = [Player]()

let formatter = NumberFormatter()



override func viewDidLoad() {


    let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style:     UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action:     #selector(myLeftSideBarButtonItemTapped(_:)))

    self.title = "Select"

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton

    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 100.0
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0


    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("NBATodaysPlayers")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        var players = [Player]()
        for player in snapshot.children {

            players.append(Player(snapshot: player as! FIRDataSnapshot))

        }
        self.players = players.sorted(by: { $0.Value > $1.Value })
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error) in
        print("error")

    }

        super.viewDidLoad()
}



func myLeftSideBarButtonItemTapped(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem!)
{
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return players.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DraftListCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! DraftListCell



    if let formattedPrice = formatter.string(from: players[indexPath.row].Value as NSNumber) {
        cell.playerPrice.text = "Game Price: \(formattedPrice)"
    }

    if let formattedRemainingPrice = formatter.string(from: 10000 - players[indexPath.row].Value as NSNumber) {
        cell.priceRemaining.text = "Remaining: \(formattedRemainingPrice)"
    }

            cell.playerName.text = players[indexPath.row].Name
            cell.injuredLabel.text = players[indexPath.row].Inj
            cell.vsLabel.text = players[indexPath.row].visiting + " @ " + players[indexPath.row].home
            cell.gameTimeLabel.text = players[indexPath.row].game_time
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
            cell.backgroundColor = .black



            return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BuyStats", sender: indexPath);
}





override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "BuyStats" {

        let buyStats =  segue.destination as! BuyStats

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            let player = players[indexPath.row]

            buyStats.selectedPlayer = player



        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `cellForRowAt` add following:

```
if cell.isSelected == true {
     tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
}
```

Or if you want to do this specifically by Segue. You can set a global variable let's say `deselectAll` and check if it's true in `cellForRowAt`

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi inokey, thank you for the help. My problem turned out to be a little different. I was returning a generic UITableViewCell() from cellForRowAtIndex. I should have been returning the reusable "cell". I fixed this and the problem went away.

Comment: If that's the issue then u should now close this question @DarkhorseFantasySports